# Extract/delete part of text in VBA

Tags: excel, vba, string, replace, extract

My dataset contains of cars on certain locations. The program that generates the locations usually gives a letter (like "A", "B" or "C"). However, sometimes it shows "road along A" as location. For formatting purposes I'd like to delete "road along" from the string in a VBA script. This really needs to be done in VBA since my dataset is quite large.

This is an example (car 4):

[image: Example]

I tried:

```
If Instr(Location, "road along")>0 Then
    replace("road along","")
Else Do Nothing
End If
```

Comment: You could do this much easier by using excels built in "Replace all" function. Press `Crtl+H` and replace the entire string you want to cut out by nothing. It'll be gone from your dataset in an instant.

Comment: That was easier than I thought. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

In VBA find and replace functionality (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>) is performed like this:

```
Sub find_replace()
  Range("B:B").replace "Road along ", ""
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

For completion I'll post this as an answer as well:

If you need to cut out a standard bit from an excel string throughout your document, a VBA function could definitely do the trick, but it's much easier and quicker to use the built in [find and replace](https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/2015/09/29/using-excel-find-replace/) functionality. This is optimised much more, and will replace the every instance of your string much faster.

To cut out a string just replace by nothing. Don't forget to add any trailing and/or leading spaces so they aren't left over.

If you need to do this for a set range, rather than your whole  document, make sure to select that range before using find and replace. It will then run in the selected range rather than your whole document.

Shortcut: `Crtl+H` or menu: `Home > Find & Select > Replace`